# Equation involving a triangle

Tags: equation-solving, geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> **Question**
>   ：In a Triangle,Sin∠A:Sin∠B:Sin∠C = ∠A:∠B:∠C,what's the specific value of ∠A，∠B，∠C? [How to prove A=B=C=π/3 is the only answer]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
{NSolve[Sin[x]/x == Sin[y]/y == Sin[z]/z && 0 < x < Pi && 
 0 < y < Pi && 0 < z < Pi && x + y + z = Pi, {x, y, z}]}
```

Comment: How did you get that equation? What is `x` and `y`?

Comment: Do you know the law of sines, and what the sum of the angles of a triangle is?

Comment: @Anjan Kumar       Sorry, now I have changed the code

Comment: @J. M.♦   Sorry,now I have changed the code.

Comment: @CcccB Try this: `FindRoot[{Sin[x]/x == Sin[y]/y, Sin[y]/y == Sin[z]/z, 
  x + y + z == Pi}, {x, 1}, {y, 1}, {z, 1}]`

Comment: @AnjanKumar - append this `/. x_?NumericQ :> RootApproximant[x/Pi]*Pi`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.

Comment: @Anjan Kumar Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

> Sin∠A:Sin∠B:Sin∠C = ∠A:∠B:∠C

means that

> $$\frac{∠A}{∠B}=\frac{\sin∠A}{\sin∠B}~~~,~~~\frac{∠B}{∠C}=\frac{\sin∠B}{\sin∠C}~~~,~~~\frac{∠A}{∠C}=\frac{\sin∠A}{\sin∠C}$$

This can be rearranged to

> $$\frac{\sin∠B}{∠B}=\frac{\sin∠A}{∠A}~~~,~~~\frac{\sin∠C}{∠C}=\frac{\sin∠B}{∠B}~~~,~~~\frac{\sin∠C}{∠C}=\frac{\sin∠A}{∠A}$$

Treating `∠A,∠B,∠C` as independent continuous variables, we see that all three of them have to be constant, since left hand side and right hand side of all above equations depend on disjoint variables only. Additionally, due to the complete symmetry of how `∠A,∠B,∠C` enter the problem, all three of them will have the same value $\alpha$. In a triangle we have

> $$∠A+∠B+∠C=3\alpha=\pi$$

Which is sufficient to conclude $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

**UPDATE**

Additionally, and maybe more appropriately for Mathematica use, once we eliminate i.e. `∠C` as `∠C=Pi-∠A-∠B`, we can explicitly check that within the appropriate range of angles there exists only exactly one solution:

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x]/x - Sin[\[Pi] - x - y]/(\[Pi] - x - y) == 0, 
    Sin[y]/y - Sin[\[Pi] - x - y]/(\[Pi] - x - y) == 0, , Sin[x]/x - Sin[y]/y == 0}, 
    {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]// Quiet
```

> [image]

Which must be the one we found.